# I need to search some directory looking for DAV files and if there is trigger a task

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, exists

I need to run a script recursively in the directory and trigger some functions if DAV files exist. However, the code does not work correctly. I need the process of executing task 01 if it does not exist in the DAV file, and perform the task 02 execution case in the DAV file.

code:

link for download file test: 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/78w681qb4r29t6q/AABd7H73uFsl1JDGtIPEnVQHa?dl=0

```
cd E:\TESTE\1002
:LOOP01
For /R %%G in (*.Dav) do IF NOT EXIST "%%G" GOTO SKIP01
:LOOP02
For /R %%G in (*.Dav) do IF EXIST "%%G" GOTO SKIP02
:SKIP01 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 10 -w 600 >NUL 
GOTO LOOP01 
:SKIP02 
for %%A IN (*.dav) do ffmpeg -i "%%A" -r 0.2 -bt 20M -s 480x300 "%%~nA"%%03d.jpg
GOTO LOOP01
```

Running it even enters the subfolders of the specified directory, recognizes the DAV files, but keeps repeating the line of LOOP 01, and does not go to GOTO SKIP01.
I would like if there is a DAV file it goes straight to LOOP02 and calls GOTO skip02.

Comment: This should be about all you need: `for /r %%A IN (*.dav) do ffmpeg -i "%%A" -r 0.2 -bt 20M -s 480x300 "%%~nA.jpg"`

Comment: `%~nA` is the filename.  What where you trying to do with `%%03d`

Comment: What OS? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: Instead of telling us about the script tell us what you are trying to do.  Be exact, thorough, measured, complete.  From a to z. Tell us everything you are trying to do. Put it in your question not as a comment.